# How to convert a dataframe to RDD[String, String]?

Tags: scala, dataframe, rdd

How to convert a dataframe to RDD[String, String] ?

I have a data frame

```
df : [id : String, coutry :String, title: String]
```

How to do I convert it to RDD[String, String] where the first column would be key and the json string made of remaining columns would be value ?

```
key : id
value : {coutry: "US", title : "MK"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not have a `RDD[String, String]`. RDD takes only 1 `type parameter` so what you want is `RDD[(String, String)]`.

```
df.rdd
  .map(row => {
    val id = row.getString(0)
    val country = row.getString(1)
    val title = row.getString(2)

    val jsonString = s"{country: $country, title: $title}"

    (id, jsonString)
  })
```

Comment: A `dataframe` has an underlying `RDD[Row]` which works as the actual data holder. If your `dataframe` is like what you provided then every `Row` of the underlying `rdd` will have those three fields. And if your `dataframe` has different structure you should be able to adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There is DataFrame.toJSON that returns an RDD[String]，based on this method，you can do the transformation yourself